# Control IP Address to access URL on Linux

Tags: linux, firewall, url

I have a J2EE application deployed on linux cloud over internet accessed through HTTP URL. Now, I want to restrict the IP addresses who can access it. Kindly suggest if this is achievable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done a couple of ways, the easiest may be using iptables

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 12.34.56.78 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

however if you are using a reverse proxy which for a J2EE application I would assume that you are, you can look at IP whitelisting in your proxy of choice, see the following;

Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

NGINX: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/

Comment: Does that mean only IP Address 12.34.56.78 can access the URL and no other IP are allowed ?

Comment: this would mean that only this IP is allowed to connect to the server on port 80 (http) UNLESS you have other ACCEPT rule for the same port or if the default action is ACCEPT, depending on what you are using as your proxy you can do it per site

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked for me. The issue was that there is already a rule which allows all the IP addresses overriding the specific ip address. I had deleted the below rule and added IP specific.

```
    iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```